# Python Variable in HTML file

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to put current month and current year into HTML file

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3


from datetime import datetime

current_month = datetime.now().strftime('%B')
currentYear = datetime.now().year


html_str="""
<br></br>
<caption><b>Project: </b></caption>Client Projects
<br></br>
<caption><b>Issue Type: </b></caption>Managed Services
<br></br>
<caption><b>Summary: </b></caption>OC SPLA usage report for current_month-currentYear
"""

Html_file= open("1.html","w")
Html_file.write(html_str)
Html_file.close()
```

But as output i'm getting

```
OC SPLA usage report for current_month-currentYear
```

Instead of

```
OC SPLA usage report for June-2018
```

Comment: @Tomalak, i tried it already before posting question here

Comment: The answers in the duplicate question show *exactly* what you need to do. Also, your question does not indicate that you have tried.

Comment: sorrym, i made a typo when trying it-it works now, thank You

Comment: '<caption><b>Summary: </b></caption>OC SPLA usage report for {current_month}-{currentYear}
""".format(**locals())'  works, thanks @Tomalak for pointing me to right link

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out after all!

Comment: I'm not a developer, that's why i had issues to grasp it at first

Comment: No problem at all. For reference, the act of getting variable values into a string is called "interpolation". Different languages have different syntax, but most can do it one way or the other. Using `f'{current_month}'` (note the `f` in front of the string) is another way that works in Python.